# Python : Trouble pickling model using pickle library

Tags: python, django, pickle

Ok, I am trying to dump my ML model using Pickle library but everytime I am trying to use it in my Django app it gives me error **"TypeError: must be char, not unicode"** I had absolutely no Idea what is the problem so I tried printing my pickled object after dumping and it shows

```
        <Class "NoneType" >
```

I thought this might be the reason for the problem.

I am dumping the model like this:

```
         joblib.dump(clf,open("rec_pickle_3.pkl","wb"))
```

and loading it like this:

```
         classifier=joblib.load(open("Recommender/rec_pickle_3.pkl", "rb"))
```

Please help, as I have absolutely no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It is version problem, pickle has some problem with python 2.7x try it with python 3 and everything will be working fine.